# Form POST to a directory without trailing slash?

Tags: forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post, http-put

I have a form of this type:

```
<form action="/directory/" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

And an `index.php` inside `/directory/` which process the form.

I want to drop the trailing slash from the form, making it `="/directory`,
but the form won'y load correctly.

I've tried adding this rewrite rule to .htaccess, but it didn't help, maybe it's written wrong:

`RewriteRule ^directory?$ directory/ [L]`

Also, what if I would want to make it:

```
<form action="/directory/post" method="POST" target="_blank">,
```

and would like the file that process this to be `/directory/process.php`, how would I change it then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add trailing slash on all URLs use this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

if you just want on directory then use this

```
RewriteRule ^directory$ directory/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: why is that [R=301] necessary? basically I don't want any crawler to see that, and it didn't really move permanenty, it's just my way of structuring the links, so i'm not sure about this

Comment: In that case omit R=301. But I would also redirect links with / to the ones without / with R=301 as it's not such good idea to use both.